# Specialization of class for vectors of specific type_trait

Tags: c++, templates, vector, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize hash to include std::vector for all arithmetic types, but it's throwing a few errors

```
./includes/helpers.hpp:14:22: error: default template argument in a class template partial specialization
      typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<dtype>::value> >
                 ^
./includes/helpers.hpp:16:8: error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
struct hash<std::vector<dtype> >
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to follow as close as I could with different enable_if_t guides. But it doesn't seem to be working, what am I doing wrong?

It seems to work without using enable_if_t. But then there would be a possible conflict with vectors that shouldn't use this hash

This is my code so far (editted to be more "complete")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

namespace std {

    template <typename dtype,
              typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_arithmetic<dtype>::value> >

    struct hash<std::vector<dtype> > {
        size_t operator()(const std::vector<dtype> &input)
        {
            //perform hash
        }
    };
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const vector<int> i{1,2,3,4};
    cout << hash<vector<int>>()(i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I never encountered such an application of `enable_if_t` as the default value for an unnamed template argument. Could you provide the links to the guides you mentioned?

Comment: @Omni It's not really a guide, but I just used two different sources and hoped it'll just work. For the "default value for an unnamed template" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if says it should work (scroll down for number 5).

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why not just put `static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<dtype>::value, "!");` in the struct body?

Comment: @RSahu Hopefully that is more complete

Comment: @HenriMenke. It's not exactly equivalent. EG: If I try to create a different hash for integral values and floating point values, it'll throw an error. It'll work for this example, but it's not 100% proper

Comment: Even if you could doing so is not legal under the current standard; you may only specialize templates on types that depend on user-provided types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `std::hash` has only a single template parameter and you cannot add an additional defaulted template parameter in a partial specialization.  So you have several choices, depending on what you want to do with your hash.

Please also rethink your approach.  This [comment by Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47964496/specialization-of-class-for-vectors-of-specific-type-trait/47964693?noredirect=1#comment82899254_47964693) is very useful:

> You may not specialize templates in std unless the specialization depends on a user-provided type. – Yakk

You can easily fix thisby not putting your own `hash` into the `std` namespace.

1. You could simply remove the `enable_if` from the template argument list and replace it with a

   ```
   static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<dtype>::value, "!");
   ```

   in the struct body, given that you only ever want to hash vectors of arithmetic type.
2. SFINAE on the call operator.  This way, you have to provide all the hash methods for all other vector types within the same struct.  Also you have to go through some funny business of repeating the template parameter to make the compiler happy.  It's very important that your SFINAE criteria are mutually exclusive, otherwise you'll get horrible errors.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <type_traits>
   #include <vector>

   namespace std {

   template< typename dtype >
   struct hash< std::vector<dtype> >
   {
       template< typename T = dtype >
       std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, size_t>
       operator()(const std::vector<T> &input) const
       {
           constexpr size_t FNV_prime = 1099511628211ul;
           constexpr size_t FNV_offset = 14695981039346656037ul;

           size_t hashed = FNV_offset;
           for(const auto &n:input)
           {
               hashed ^= n;
               hashed *= FNV_prime;
           }
           return hashed;
       }

       template< typename T = dtype >
       std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, size_t>
       operator()(const std::vector<T> &input) const
       {
           std::cout << "No hash for you :-(\n";
           return 0;
       }
   };

   } // namespace std


   int main() {
       {
           std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
           size_t hash = std::hash<std::vector<int>>{}(v);
           std::cout << hash << "\n";
       }

       {
           std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello", "world!"};
           size_t hash = std::hash<std::vector<std::string>>{}(v);
           std::cout << hash << "\n";
       }
   }
   ```

   <kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aj5wkb00hU6tfHHB)</kbd>
3. You can also declare your own struct for hashing and add as many template parameters as you want.  Then you just need `std::hash` to inherit from your custom struct.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <type_traits>
   #include <vector>

   template < typename T, bool = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value >
   struct vector_hash;

   template < typename T>
   struct vector_hash<T,true> {
       size_t operator()(std::vector<T> const &input) const
       {
           constexpr size_t FNV_prime = 1099511628211ul;
           constexpr size_t FNV_offset = 14695981039346656037ul;

           size_t hashed = FNV_offset;
           for(const auto &n:input)
           {
               hashed ^= n;
               hashed *= FNV_prime;
           }
           return hashed;
       }
   };


   template < typename T>
   struct vector_hash<T,false> {
       size_t operator()(std::vector<T> const &) const
       {
           std::cout << "No hash for you :-(\n";
           return 0;
       }
   };

   namespace std {

   template< typename dtype >
   struct hash< std::vector<dtype> > : vector_hash<dtype> {};

   } // namespace std


   int main() {
       {
           std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
           size_t hash = std::hash<std::vector<int>>{}(v);
           std::cout << hash << "\n";
       }

       {
           std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello", "world!"};
           size_t hash = std::hash<std::vector<std::string>>{}(v);
           std::cout << hash << "\n";
       }
   }
   ```

   <kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ElyYNyOwcApPsEZb)</kbd>

Comment: @Michael I have added another method based on inheritance.

Comment: This answer advises writing an ill formed program, no diagnostic required in 1 and 2.  You may not specialize templates in std unless the specialization depends on a user-provided type.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for your help. It's quite thorough, and seems a little bit obvious now that I see the issue. I was wondering why it wasn't working for hash but I remembered it was working in other scenarios.

Comment: Cool solution. Yet I find it unsettling that in C++ basic type enabling/disabling (what I would consider a basic maneuver for template programming) like this still feels like a hack.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, indeed.  I have added this to my answer.  TBH, I wouldn't use this myself but rather use `boost::hash_value`.

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal to specialize a template in namespace std, unless you do it on a user provuded type.  Vector is not user provided.

What you need to do is:

```
namespace helper{
  template<class T, class=void>
  struct hash:std::hash<T>{};
}
```

now you can do usual sfinae tricks with helper's hash, or extend it willy-nilly.

```
namespace helper {
  template <typename dtype>
  struct hash<std::vector<dtype>,
     std::enable_if_t< std::is_arithmetic<dtype>::value> 
  > {
    size_t operator()(const std::vector<dtype> &input) const {
        //perform hash
    }
  };
}
```

Simply pass `helper::hash<T>` in place of std hash.  The extra `void` defaulted parameter permits sfina specialization, the base spec forwards std hash, and there is no ill-formedness issues.